# Width tool playing up illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6

I have been encountering an issue whenever I try to create a new point using the width tool it does this. I am not sure why it is doing that. I think its making multiple points?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** creating additional width markers. When markers are close to each other you get sharp, drastic, changes in the width.

In CS6 you have to be **very** careful about where you click and *wait* for a marker to highlight before you click. It's **very** "buggy" and inaccurate in CS6 (at least the Mac version is).

Often you see the highlight when the cursor is *not* actually directly above a width marker.. so wait for the width marker to highlight.

CS6 is not the best implementation of the width tool.. it was new and rushed to market, *clearly* before it was refined.

Comment: It's still a bit tricky with later versions, and on Windows too, so not just Mac specific. Particularly problematic if you have one segment selected before applying the width tool. You still need to make sure it's exactly on the existing anchor.